# Creating MATLAB neural network target array from class labels

Tags: matlab, matrix, neural-network

Is there a nice one-liner, function, or matrix math based way to generate the target class array for a neural network (such as `patternnet()`) from an array of numeric class labels?

Note: By neural network target array, I mean a `num_exemplar x num_class` array with a full probability of 1 for each y index equal to the class label.

ex.

```
labels = [1, 3, 2, 4]
nntargets = *magic*
% nntargets is now [1 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 0 1];
```

Comment: The above marked duplicate should answer your problem.  I'll admit that the question is poorly worded, but the accepted answer describes exactly what you need to do.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that's perfect, thanks for your assistance!